# How to delete podcast on Google Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music

I use Google Play Music and I need to delete old podcast, but have not been able to find a way to do it. Any ideas that might assist?

Comment: Hi, welcome to [android.se]. It seems that one of the answer(s) helps you solving the issue. Consider accepting the answer if that answer is the best for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded them within Google Play Music, you can delete them one at a time.

- Tap the info icon to open the episode details
- Tap the check mark that indicates it is downloaded
- A menu will pop us asking if you want to "REMOVE" or "MANAGE SUBSCRIPTION".  Tap Remove.

To delete all episodes of a podcast, within the MANAGE SUBSCRIPTION menu, unsubscribe and save.  If you still want to be subscribed, the resubscribe and reset your download preferences in the process.

Answer (score 0):

How did you load them on there, usually you can go into My files and go to the podcast folder and delete them manually

Comment: No problem glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

go to settings 
pick music or podcasts (which ever you want to get rid of)
go to manage downloads
click the symbol to the right of each item you want to get rid of
and it will be deleted and disappear from list